# Prevent default key handling in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, keyboard, internet-explorer-9

I want to disable some default browser keys (CTRL + F, ALT + ENTER) as they do not make sense in my application scenario. What I've read so far the most important thing to disable these events in IE9 is to set the keyCode to 0 in this case, however I always get an "Access denied" error when I do this.

This is my code:

```
var fnOnKeyDown = function(event)
{
  if(!event)
  {
    event = window.event;
  }
  if(event.preventDefault)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  event.returnValue = false;
  event.cancelBubble = true;
  event.keyCode = 0;      
  return false;  
};

window.document.onkeydown = fnOnKeyDown;
```

As mentioned, the line event.keyCode = 0 throws an error "Access denied". When I remove it or put it into an empty try/catch block it doesn't throw the error but the default browser key handling is not suppressed anymore.

Comment: I'm not Windows. These don't go through either?; http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/wHvRb/

Comment: This might also be resourceful while using jQuery; http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/downloads/list

Comment: try using meta key in event object? There is difference between win and mac

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you don't mean ie7? I didn't seem to have a problem in ie9...

anyway, here is a post from microsoft on your issue

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934364

> To resolve this problem, change the code that assigns the
>   event.keyCode property so that it does not change the value. The
>   change in the code lets you use the SHIFT key or the CTRL key to load
>   pages from the local disk
>
> Alternatively, you can host the Web pages on a Web server. This makes
>   sure that the event.keyCode property in the script runs correctly.

also, if possible I would advise the use of jquery. frameworks like that often handle various browser issues for you through a common interface.

Answer (score 1):

`event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` should be enough - you shouldn't need to change any of the properties of the event itself.